# Use classes defined in traits on the same package in scala.

Tags: scala, traits

I believe that in Scala I can use the classes defined in other traits inside my trait. Something like the following:

```
trait A{
  sealed abstract class C
}

trait B{
  import A.C
  val l: List[C]
}
```

However, I'm getting that neither A nor  C are recognized.

What  am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need imports here. `A` and `C` are accessible inside `B` in type position without imports.

Try

```
trait A {
  sealed abstract class C
}

trait B {
  val l: List[A#C]
}
```

or

```
trait A {
  sealed abstract class C
}

trait B {
  type C = A#C
  val l: List[C]
}
```

Otherwise you could mean

```
trait A {
  sealed abstract class C
}

val a = new A {}

trait B {
  import a.C
  val l: List[C]
}
```

or

```
object A {
  sealed abstract class C
}

trait B {
  import A.C
  val l: List[C]
}
```

Comment: great! why is it that they use # instead of import?

Comment: Because it's not import, it's type projection. Once again, you don't need imports here. You should read about path-dependent types and type projections in Scala.